# Recalculate a Field with data from another field, ignoring NULL values (take two!)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I am having an issue populating a field with data in a secondary field in ArcMap using the field calculator, below is what I put together...

I have a Feature Class in a Geodatabase with a field for pipe *Diameter*. I also have a shapefile with a field for pipe *Height*. The shapefile is from field verification work that verified a variety of pipe characteristics. I have joined the shapefile to the Feature Class in ArcMap, see the image below.

[image]

I would like to recalculate the *Diameter* field using Field Calculator and the Python Parser. The *Diameter* field would be updated with that information in the *Height* field, any null values would keep the data in the *Diameter* field. I have the following Pre-Logic Script Code defined:

```
def IgnoreNull (orginal, field):
 if field is None:
      return original
 else:
      return field
```

The field calculation line is coded as:

```
IgnoreNull (!GravitySewer.Diameter!, !Assets01132023_2.Height!)
```

I know for a fact this worked in the past when I did it last in 2017, I saved the script ofr dutyre use. When I implement this recently the Null values from *Height* replaced the values in the *Diameter* field rather that leave the existng *Diameter* data.

Comment: An update to a question would normally be considered a duplicate of it.  Why shouldn't this one?

Comment: Ok, so how do I get assistance on a new issue that has arisen? The original working solution isn't working?

Comment: By explaining at the start of this question why it is a different question and not starting by describing it as an update to the original.

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully enough to try and get some assistance. I appreciate the information so that I am hopefully contributing to the community and not making it more confusing...

Comment: Could be related to the join since shape files don't support NULL.  Try exporting the joined table to a new table and try it on that new table.  If it works as expected, then you know the problem is from the join.

Comment: @bixb0012, that did the trick. How should we set this up so that I can mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: If I find some time to investigate a bit more to have a better explanation, I will post an answer; otherwise, I am just glad you got it sorted.